# Why is datetime being truncated in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to filter pandas using the time stamp. This works fine for all hours except 0. If I filter for dt.hour = 0, only the date is displayed and not the time. How can I have the time displayed too?

```
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': [datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 14, 12, 30),
                                datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 14, 0, 0), 
                                datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 14, 10, 30),
                                datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 14, 15, 30)]})

print(df[df['datetime'].dt.hour == 10])
print(df[df['datetime'].dt.hour == 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `strftime`:

```
print(df[df['datetime'].dt.hour == 0].datetime.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The result is:

```
1    2005-07-14 00:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```